# i want only jpg and png file save in database in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I want to save files with extensions jpg & png but am having trouble.

I've tried `image => 'required|mime:jpg'` unsuccessfully.

Basically, I want to store images whose extension is jpg and png by using laravel. Here is my code:

```php
public function addImages(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [
        'image' => 'Please Enter description',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|max:3' //only allow this type extension file.
    ]);



    $product_id = request('product_id');
    $array = array();
    foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
    {
        //$allowedfileExtension=['pdf','jpg','png','docx'];
        $name=time() . '.' .$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if(!in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension));
        {
        }

        $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
        $img = "/public/images/".$name;   
        $id =  DB::table('product_image')->insert(array('product_id'=>$product_id,'image'=>$img));
    }

    //image upoad code
    //return $request->all();

    $addImages = $this->addMultipleImage($id,$array);

    Session::flash('message', 'Image Added successfully!');

    return redirect("admin/edit-product/$product_id"); 
    }
}
```

Tell me, where I am going wrong?

Comment: When posting a code-heavy question, it is considered polite to clean up the code and format it as much as possible to make it easier for us to read it. Ideally you should provide with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem and does not include noise that is not relevant to the question. This would greatly increase the changes of anyone going through the code and providing a solution. In addition, most of the time when cleaning up your code to create the minimal example you will end up finding the solution yourself

Comment: Which files extensions you want to allow upload? What do you mean does not work? How is it not working?

Comment: i want jpg and png but this upload all files

Answer (score 1):

Try this validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png|max:50' //max size allowed will be 50kb
]);
```

Or try this

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'image' => 'image|required|mimes:png,jpg|max:50'
]);
```

Comment: could we you some  code to check extensions in laravel